# SpringData/Hibernate @ManyToOne cascading automatically when it should not

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Given two entities like so

```
@Entity
public class Thing {
  @ManyToOne
  private ThingType thingType;
  ...
}

@Entity
public class ThingType {
  private String name;
  ...
}
```

From everything I have read, the default cascade should be nothing so if I get a reference to a `Thing thing`, and change the name field of its `ThingType`, then using a `JpaRepository<Thing, Long>` call `thingRepo.save(thing)`, I would expect the change to `ThingType`s name not to be persisted.

However this is not the case and the change is persisted. I am not sure why this is happening? What I am missing here?

Relevant versions:

- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.7.RELEASE
- org.hibernate:hibernate-core:jar:5.0.12.Final
- org.springframework.data:spring-data-jpa:jar:1.11.7.RELEASE

Answer (score 1):

Well, I would have expected the same, but it seems that Hibernate has its own default behaviour. In the [Hibernate forum](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=976965) someone asked almost the same question. The answer refers to the Hibernate "dirty check" feature, which will detect and perstst/merge the change. You might change that behaviour by using Hibernate's [Cascade](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-hibspec-cascade) annotation.

Answer (score 1):

Well cascading is something else, let me ask you something. Do following things:

```
Thing thing = session.get(Thing .class, someId);
thing.getThingType().setTitle("new title");
```

and nothing more, again you see hibernate updates `thingType`.

It is called dirty checking, as long as an entity is attached to an active hibernate session, and its persistence state changes hibernate automatically updates its associated row in database. Event without calling a save or update.

So what is cascade?
Consider following case:

```
Thing myThing = new Thing();
ThingType myThingType = new ThingType();
myThing.setThingType(myThingType);
session.save(myThing);
```

if the association cascade type is not set, then you will get an exception, because you are referencing a transient `thingType` object. But if you set the cascade type to persist, then hibernate first saves the `thingType` and then saves the `thing`, and everything goes fine.

So remember, if you fetch an object, then update its properties in the same session, there is no need to call a `update` or `saveOrUpdate` method on hibernate session (or jpa entityManager) because it is already in `attached` state, and its state is traced by hibernate.

Comment: I had assumed this was a cascade merge, but it seems that merge is not an update as such, but merging an un-managed object with the managed version that it matches (by id generally), is that correct?

Comment: I didn't get what your question is, but have you detached your object before? I'm not sure, but I think you shall detach both objects (`Thing` and `ThingType`), because when you fetch the `Thing` hibernate fetches the `ThingType` too, and both are attached to session. Maybe you've just detached the `Thing` and `ThingType` was still managed by session.